# How to play sound/audio on a bluetooth device by CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to make an app to find the lost Bluetooth device (like Airpod). The idea is the same as [Wunderfind](https://apps.apple.com/app/find-lost-device/id1458601441).

With CoreBluetooth, I can display nearby Bluetooth devices with signal strength and distance. But I don't know how to play a sound/audio on these devices (to help the user to find it easily).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a direct way to do this with CoreBluetooth. LE Audio was just announced last month (6/7 Jan 2020) and it will take a few months or maybe even years for devices to begin supporting this. CoreBluetooth does not support transferring audio of any kind so your next best solution is to transfer normal BLE GATT packets, and then have the receiving device play some audio on reception of that specific sequence of packets. This means that your solution will be device specific and you'll have to work on the app side (on the iOS device) and the remote device that is playing the audio.

Some references for this:-

- [CoreBluetooth and audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185145/corebluetooth-and-audio-stream)
- [how to find Bluetooth audio devices in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896528/how-to-find-bluetooth-audio-devices-in-ios)
- [What profile can I use with CoreBluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768599/what-profile-can-i-use-with-corebluetooth)
- [What is LE Audio](https://www.soundguys.com/le-audio-lc3-explained-28192/)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A Primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer?utm_sq=g7jck8212t&utm_source=LinkedIn&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=PhillipJohnston&utm_content=Linkstoshare)